# Cross-browser event handling

Tags: javascript, events, cross-browser, addeventlistener, attachevent

I need a cross-browser function for registering event handlers and a (mostly) consistent handler experience. I don't need the full weight or functionality of a library such as jQuery, so I've written my own. I believe I've accomplished my goals with the code below, and so far my testing has been successful, but I've been staring at it for too long. Are there any flaws in my logic or gotchas that I'm missing?

**EDIT 1:** Commented each block with browser intent for clarity. Updated IE block to not call `func` right away (thanks to [Andy E's keen eyes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568753/3568827#3568827)).

**EDIT 2:** Updated IE block to call `func.call()` with `this` instead of `elem`.

**EDIT 3:** Updated to pass [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) with "the Good Parts."

```
function hookEvent(elem, evt, func)
{
    if (typeof elem === "string")
    {
        elem = document.getElementById(elem);
    }
    if (!elem)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var old, r;
    if (elem.addEventListener)  //w3c
    {
        elem.addEventListener(evt, func, false);
        r = true;
    }
    else if (elem.attachEvent)  //ie
    {
        elem[evt + func] = function ()
        {
            func.call(this, window.event);
        };
        r = elem.attachEvent("on" + evt, elem[evt + func]);
    }
    else                        //old
    {
        old = elem["on" + evt] ? elem["on" + evt] : function (e) { };
        elem["on" + evt] = function (e)
        {
            if (!e)
            {
                e = window.event;
            }
            old.call(this, e);
            func.call(this, e);
        };
        r = true;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: jQuery is a very lightweight library. What's wrong with using it? Someone's already done all the work for you. Or are you just not interested in learning it?

Comment: @Bears will eat you - 66K plus, compared to this, is far from lightweight. Especially if that's all he needs.



@Bill Ayakatubby - By "cross browser", you really mean, "standard stuff that IE doesn't handle properly".

Comment: @Bears: At this point in time, the only cross-browser concern I have is event registration, so I have no need of jQuery or another library. If my situation changes, I'll reevaluate the necessity of a library.

Comment: There's really little point in the last branch now. There are no major browsers left that don't support either `addEventListener` or `attachEvent`.

Comment: migrate to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

There's a problem on this line:

```
r = elem.attachEvent("on" + evt, func.call(elem, window.event));
```

This will execute *func()* immediately, instead of attaching it as a handler for the event.  Instead, the return value of *func()* will be assigned to the event, which will throw an error if it's type isn't `"function"`.

I can understand that you don't want to use a framework, but many (*many*) others have written cross-browser event handling snippets.  [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/flexible-javascript-events/) has one version, Google for "javascript addEvent" for many more.

http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+addevent

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Andy. I've updated my code to reflect your find.